# Is my (first) proof by induction correct?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I am self-studying and would very much appreciate some feedback on my first ever induction proof.

Let $y_1 = 6$, and for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ define $y_{n+1} = (2y_n - 6)/3$. Use induction to prove the sequence satisfies $y_n > -6$.

First, we'll prove the base case. Because we've been given $y_1 = 6 > -6$, our base case will be $n=2$:

$y_2 = (2y_1-6)/3 = (2(6)-6)/3 = 2 > -6.$

Next, the induction step. Assume $y_{n+1} > -6$. Let's then prove $y_{n+2} > -6$ for some $y_{n+1}$. We'll do this by contradiction, assuming $y_{n+2} = (2y_{n+1}-6)/3 < -6$. Observe:

$$(2y_{n+1}-6)/3 < -6,$$
$$2y_{n+1}-6 < -18,$$
$$2y_{n+1} < -12,$$
$$y_{n+1} < -6,$$

which contradicts our initial assumption that $y_{n+1} > -6$. Thus, $y_{n+2} > -6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the base case $n=1$ despite it holding automatically. In general for induction proofs it is more natural to write 'assume for $n$, then true for $n+1$', although it is essentially the same as what you have done. Having said that, for the proof by contradiction to work you need to start by assuming the **precise opposite** of what you are trying to prove, so assume $y_{n+2}\leq -6$ instead and you're good to go.

A good way to think of induction proofs is like a 'domino effect'. Check that it works for the first domino ($n=1$), and that if it works for $n$ then it must work for $n+1$. It then must work for all $n\geq 1$ by induction.

*A cleaner proof*: Clearly $y_1>-6$. If $y_n>-6$, then $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(2y_n-6)>-6$.

$y_1>-6$ and ($y_n>-6\implies y_{n+1}>-6$) gives that $y_n>-6$ by induction for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Hello!  There is no opportunity in the suggested edits review to give feedback to those suggesting edits; but I've taken note of the high quality of your edits, and want to let you know that your suggested edits are very much appreciated, and a breath of fresh air for reviewers like me.  Keep up the good work, Very Forgetful Functor!

Comment: @amWhy Thank you! :)